# Handling personal information

Tags: discussion

I recently read through a post where the questioner had added his/her personal e-mail address.

I immediately edited the post to remove it. But for some reason I don't know if that was the right thing to do.

How should we handle personal information like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me that sounds like part of a signature? In that case I think it was the right choice to edit it out.

If it was part of the sample code for example, editing it out also seems like the correct choice. Since the user has the possibly to rollback your changes if he/she feels that the edit was invalid it is really no major problem.

I'm more concerned when people manages to copy in namespaces etc. containing client names though, since that company probably does not want their name and projects to be spread without their concent

Comment: In this case the user wanted responses to his question directed to his e-mail instead of SPSE.

Comment: Then it was definitely a correct decision, that is no where near the purpose of this community :)

Comment: +1 we definitely don't want anyone's personal information in a question or answer.